# How make gulp-replace-task replace text in html file?

Tags: gulp

I have the following text in a index.html file I want to replace with  gulp-replace-task:

```
<img src="assets/images/logo

<img style="width:100px;height:100px;" src="assets/ima
```

I want to make it such that all instances of "assets" are replaced with "my/stuff".

I tried the following, but it is not working:

```
gulp.task('default', function() {
    gulp.src('./index.html')
        .pipe(replace({
            patterns: [
                {
                    match: '/assets/g',
                    replacement: 'my/stuff'
                }
            ]
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Match can be a string but if you want to use regexp remove the quotes `'` around the regexp.

```
gulp.task('default', function() {
    gulp.src('./index.html')
        .pipe(replace({
            patterns: [
                {
                    match: /assets/g,
                    replacement: 'my/stuff'
                }
            ]
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
```

Answer (score 3):

You may also use module [gulp-string-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-string-replace) which supports manages with regex, string or even functions.

Example:

Regex:

```
var replace = require('gulp-string-replace');

gulp.task('replace_1', function() {
  gulp.src(["./config.js"]) // Every file allown. 
    .pipe(replace(new RegExp('@env@', 'g'), 'production'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/config.js'))
});
```

String:

```
gulp.task('replace_1', function() {
  gulp.src(["./config.js"]) // Every file allown. 
    .pipe(replace('environment', 'production'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/config.js'))
});
```

Function:

```
gulp.task('replace_1', function() {
  gulp.src(["./config.js"]) // Every file allown. 
    .pipe(replace('environment', function () {
       return 'production';
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/config.js'))
});
```

Comment: what purpose does the Function serve?  It passes no useful parameters.